# Create and process a list of generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have a list of values that I need to store that can be of any type (mostly int, double, date, ...) at runtime. Later I need to process these. What is the way I should approach this problem?

This is what I have come up with, and it appears to work, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to approach this problem.

```
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    list.add("hello");
    list.add(1);
    list.add(0.5);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        Object obj = list.get(i);

        if (obj instanceof Integer)
        {
            System.out.println((double)obj);
        }
        else if (obj instanceof String)
        {
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to deal with type.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It has to be way too **generic** to hold `int`,`double`,`Date` etc..

Comment: you should rethink the way you structure the data to avoid this

Comment: Your approach seems fine. Sometimes this kind of checking with `instanceof` cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

I realize your example is probably simplified, but I'd introduce a wrapper for all of them to represent whatever is common between them in your world.  Here's an example:

```
interface PrintableThing {
   string specialToString();
}

class IntPrintable implements PrintableThing {
    private final int int_;

    public IntPrintable(int a) { int_ = a; }
    public specialToString() { return ((double)int_).toString(); }
}
```

And so on.  Now you can just iterate over a list of `ArrayList<PrintableThing>` and ask each element to do it's `specialToString` method.

Comment: Problem is that they don't really shared anything in common. They are simply values. I don't know how they are going to be processed, so I'd rather not convert a date to a string and then back to a date again when it needs to be processed.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways of doing it I can think of:

1. As your provided code shows, **check every object with `instanceof`** in else-if's.
2. **Create an abstract class (or interface)** with a set of methods you will apply to objects, e.g. `toString()` (which – in many cases – is already implemented the way you want it to be).

Comment: But sometimes it may not suit your needs, so you'll need to create your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

additionally you can create a custom javabean class to hold these data types . Like this :

```
class data{
    private Double double1;
    private int int1;
    private String1;
}
```

and you can make a list of this class type :

```
List<data> l = new List<data>();
```

In my opinion that makes more sense that your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will use the generic Type to make sure that a `Collection` holds only that Type of elements. So it is not necessary to say that the elements of `ArrayList` have the type `Object` because that's normal.

And when you convert to other types, make sure you use the type you tested with `instanceof` otherwise you can encounter a `ClassCastException`. What I mean is oyur line where you converting an Object of `Integer` to an primitive double.

Otherwise it's O.K.

And one hint, instead of using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
```

you can use

```
for (Object obj : list)
```

Comment: Pretty sure its: `for (Object obj : list)`